Sound Timing: Stationary vs. Moving Source - Who Wins?
Case - 1: A stationary source emits sound and an observer stationary is at 'd' distance apart.
Case - 2: A moving source emits sound when an stationary observer is at 'd' distance apart.
Will in both cases sound be heard at the same time?

If the sound is emitted instantaneously when the distance of separation between the source and observer is d, then the time taken by sound to reach the observer is same in both the cases.
Sound wave is a pressure wave, the only important piece of information here is wave propagation speed. So once the sound wave leaves the source, it doesn't bother of the speed of the source that emitted it. The law of addition of velocities doesn't apply to a sound wave.
Unlike velocity, frequency of sound heard is not same in both the cases. Due to Doppler Effect, the frequency of sound depends on if the source is moving towards or away from the observer.
